# How to hide the rendered lines above each row in a datatable?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I am implementing a nested datatable within a column of a another datatable. This datatable is supposed to have no borders around the rows. My code is based on [Datatable with no borders](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/#With-no-borders):

Parent datatable:

```
<template>
    <article class="slds-card slds-card_boundary">
        <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
          <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
            <div class="slds-media__figure">
                <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:approval" alternative-text="Referral Approvals Summary" title="Referral Approvals Summary" size="small"></lightning-icon>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-media__body">
              <h2 class="slds-card__header-title">
              </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-no-flex">
            </div>
          </header>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-card__body"> 
          <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-no-row-hover slds-table_bordered slds-table_fixed-layout" role="grid" aria-label="Rationale referrals summary">
            <thead>
              <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                <th width="15%" class="" scope="col">
                  <div class="slds-truncate" title="Rationale Name">Column1</div>
                </th>
                <th width="10%"  class="" scope="col">
                  <div class="slds-truncate" title="Approval Status">Column2</div>
                </th>
                <th class="" scope="col">
                  <div class="slds-truncate" title="Datatable 2">Nested Datatable Column</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              
                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <td role="gridcell">
                            <div class="slds-truncate">
                            Test1
                        </div>
                        </td>
                        <td role="gridcell">
                          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Approved">Test2</div>
                      </td>   
                      <td role="gridcell">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Approved">
                                  <c-inner-table></c-inner-table>
                        </div>
                    </td>         
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <td role="gridcell">
                            <div class="slds-truncate">
                            Test1
                        </div>
                        </td>
                        <td role="gridcell">
                          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Approved">Test2</div>
                      </td>   
                      <td role="gridcell">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Approved">
                                  <c-inner-table></c--inner-table>
                        </div>
                    </td>         
                    </tr>
  
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <footer class="slds-card__footer"></footer>
    </article>
  </template>
```

Nested datatable:

```
         <template>
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_header-hidden" aria-label=" Example headless table of Opportunities with no borders ">
            <thead class="slds-assistive-text">
              <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                <th class="" scope="col">
                  <div class="slds-truncate" title="Opportunity Name">Opportunity Name</div>
                </th>
                <th class="" scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Account Name</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
              <th data-label="Opportunity Name" scope="row">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub">
                  <a href="#" tabindex="-1">Cloudhub</a>
                </div>
              </th>
              <td data-label="Account Name">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub">Cloudhub</div>
              </td>
              <td data-label="Close Date">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="4/14/2015">4/14/2015</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                <th data-label="Opportunity Name" scope="row">
                  <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub">
                    <a href="#" tabindex="-1">Cloudhub</a>
                  </div>
                </th>
                <td data-label="Account Name">
                  <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub">Cloudhub</div>
                </td>
                <td data-label="Close Date">
                  <div class="slds-truncate" title="4/14/2015">4/14/2015</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

However, each row displays a line above it to separate the rows visually, which I would like to hide:

[image]

I've tried a number of CSS properties, such as:

```
    border="0"
    border-color="white"
```

It did not help my issue. Could anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: If possible can you please share the full code which you have tried?

Comment: If i just copy paste the code above shared, I dont see any border line displayed. Can you please share exact code? Becasue it looks like there is a loop and you may creating `<table>` in loop.

Comment: @NagendraSingh Updated the code and also the image of the datatable.

Comment: @dbase1 As per your code shared in Parent datatable you have added a CSS class that's why the border is displayed. Just replace your table tab with this code. `<table
    class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_header-hidden"
    role="grid" aria-label="Rationale referrals summary">`

Comment: @TusharJadav That is really great and I will probably leave it like that, thanks a lot! Question - is it technically possible to have the lines rendered in the parent component, but not in the child nested datatable? Does it have to be both or nothing?

Comment: If your parent component has lines rendered and you can add a child component without lines. child component inherits the CSS from the parent component. that is why your parent and child both component has lines.

Comment: @TusharJadav Thanks!!!